# Java FlightRecorder not working with JDK 11?

Tags: java

I get the following error when I attempt to access the Flight Recorder on a project that uses JDK 11:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Flight Recorder features are not enabled. To enable this you need to use a Java 7u4 or later JVM started with -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder.
    at com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.FlightRecorderProvider.refresh(FlightRecorderProvider.java:110)
    at com.jrockit.mc.browser.views.JVMBrowserView$1.run(JVMBrowserView.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.services.flr.FlightRecorderException: Flight Recorder features are not enabled. To enable this you need to use a Java 7u4 or later JVM started with -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder.
    at com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.FlightRecorderProvider.refreshRecordings(FlightRecorderProvider.java:124)
    at com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.FlightRecorderProvider.refresh(FlightRecorderProvider.java:99)
    ... 8 more
```

I included the following arguments for VM options in IntelliJ IDEA:
`-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder`

The Java Mission Control application runs just fine and I can use everything on it besides the Flight Recorder. If anyone here has an idea how to get around this, that would be great.

Comment: My guess is that you need o use `Java8`.

Comment: Make sure that the Java compiler (javac), Java launcher (java) , JFR, jcmd and JMC are from the same Java distribution. In your case it should be `Java11`.

Comment: Try : `java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder 
  -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=200s,filename=flight.jfr path-to-class-file`. ***Note*** : path-to-class-file is the application's entry point *.class file.

Comment: The open-sourced release of *Flight Recorder* was added to OpenJDK for Java 11, per [*JEP 328: Flight Recorder*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328). Previously, Flight Recorder was a proprietary commercial offering from Oracle, thus the messages about `UnlockCommercialFeatures`. I suspect you are not using Java 11, or are mixing some elements from older versions. I suggest you recheck your installation, perhaps re-install Java, or try another machine.

Comment: @BasilBourque I am currently running Java 11.0.8. My instructor for udemy is operating on the same version and is having no issues on his end.

Comment: @Sedrick it does work with Java8, but I was curious why it wasn't working with Java 11. Like Amit kumar said, it could be a matter of incongruent distribution.